# I'm trying to create this commenting bot, where it comments and the comments don't repeat them selves

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

```
#this is the section where I think I need help

def random_comment():
    with open('comments.txt', 'r') as f:
        comments = [line.strip() for line in f]
    comment = random.choice(comments)
    return comment        

    #comment=============================

    for url in urls:
        print('Commenting to this post ---> ' + url)
        comment = random_comment()
        bot.get(url)
        bot.implicitly_wait(1)
        time.sleep(5)

        bot.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[2]/button').click()

        if doesnt_exist(bot, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div'):
            print('Skipped - comments disabled')
        else:
            find_textarea = (
                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div/form/textarea')
            WebDriverWait(bot, 50).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(find_textarea)
            )                                         
            comment_box = bot.find_element(*find_textarea)
            WebDriverWait(bot, 50).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(find_textarea)
            )
            comment_box.click()
            comment_box.send_keys(comment)
```

The comments are in a .txt file name comments.txt
for this testing purpose the comments are 1,2,....,10 which each number on its line.
I want the comment bot to comment them without the numbers repeating themselves.
if possible even delete the number after being commented.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make choice without repeating, you can do next things:

1. Read comments.txt just one time and save the list of all comments in variable.
2. After making a choice, you need to delete that choice from the list of all comments.

For example:

```
class Comments:
   def __init__(self):
     with open('comments.txt', 'r') as f:
       self.comments = [line.strip() for line in f]

   def choice_comment(self):
     comment = random.choice(self.comments)
     self.comments.remove(comment)
     return comment
```

If you want to delete number from comment (if file looks like:

```
1. One comment
2. Two comment
........
10. Ten comment
```

), you can split string by dot and join all strings back without first one (it is a number):

```
comment = '. '.join(comment.split('. ')[1:])
```

Comment: its giving me this error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: If you haven't any classes in your code, you can't use self in your code and you need to rewrite code and use functions
So, you need to put code in function __init__ outside of any functions without "self". (you make variable "comments" global). Also you need to delete "self" from choice_comment function.